# Selectable text on VBA form

Tags: forms, vba, label, copy-paste

I am using the following code to copy a label's text to the clipboard when a button is clicked:

```
Private Sub CopyToClipBoardButton_Click()

    CopyText labelName

End Sub
```

But instead of clicking the button,I wish I could directly select the text on the form and right click the mouse button to copy it. Is it possible?

Comment: Use a text box styled to look like a label?

Comment: You could copy the label.caption to the clipboard in the label click event.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the label.caption to the clipboard in the label click event.

```
Private Sub Label1_Click()
    With New MSForms.DataObject
        .SetText Label1.Caption
        .PutInClipboard
    End With
End Sub
```